# Link Mainpage's Sidebar to all web pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: Picture of my Sidebar]

You can see the sidebar that I have on the picture, I wanna link that sidebar to the other pages of my website so that when it edit the sidebar on the main page, I would also take effect on the other pages, what should I do to make it so? and here's my sidebar code just in case you need to see

```
<div id="site_content">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <!-- insert your sidebar items here -->
        <h3>Events</h3>
        <h4>Test Event Name</h4>
        <h5>Test Date</h5>
        <p>Test event</p>
        <p>Test event</p>
        <p>Test event</p>
        <p>Test event</p>
        <p>Test event</p>
        <p>Test event</p>

        <div id="images">
            <img id="image1" src="http://i.imgur.com/dL3io.jpg" />
            <img id="image2" src="http://i.imgur.com/qASVX.jpg" />
            <img id="image3" src="http://i.imgur.com/fLuHO.jpg" />
            <img id="image4" src="http://i.imgur.com/5Sd3Q.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div id="slider">
            <a href="#image1">1</a>
            <a href="#image2">2</a>
            <a href="#image3">3</a>
            <a href="#image4">4</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="slidess">

            <h4>&nbsp;</h4>
            <h4>Opening Hours</h4>

            <h5> Mon - 5:00am - 6:00pm</h5>
            <h5>Tue - 5:00am - 6:00pm</h5>
            <h5>Wed - 5:00am - 6:00pm</h5>
            <h5>Thu - 5:00am - 6:00pm</h5>
            <h5>Fri - 5:00am - 6:00pm</h5>
            <h5>Sat - 5:00am - 6:00pm</h5>
            <h5>Sun - 5:00am - 6:00pm<br></h5>

            <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
            <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i don't think so...

Comment: That link shows exactly how to do what you ask, and is almost identical to the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to achieve this.

```
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script> 
$(function(){
  $("#sidebar").load("sidebar.html");
});
</script>
<body>
<div id="header"></div>
</body>
</head>
```

Then add your sidebar content to another page called `sidebar.html`.

Comment: thank you, ill give it a try

Comment: This answer is almost identical to the answer for the linked question.